# How does one add labels to connector ends in visio?

Tags: visio

I'm doing some network documentation in visio 2306 and want to add port numbers to the ends of the connectors. Seeing the UML class arrows, this is obviously possible to do, but I have no luck in replicating that.

Steps so far:

- Make a new connector
- Convert connector to group
- Make text fields
- Add the text fields to the group

This *almost* works: the connector still functions nicely and the text boxes *seem* to attach to the ends.

In practice this still has 2 problems:

- The size scales relatively to the size of the connector

  - Even when that has been turned off in the shape behaviour
- The position scales relative to the center of the connector

  - Even though the text label does stay nicely attached to the connector end.

Maybe some VBA is required? I haven't looked into VBA much yet, maybe that's why I havent found a solution yet.

I have looked in the shape sheet as well, but editing the PinX and PinY value doesn't seem persist after dragging the attached shapes around.

Comment: Did you read article [Building a labelled dynamic connector in Visio](https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/04/building-a-labelled-dynamic-connector-in-visio.html) by [John Goldsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683606/johngoldsmith)?

Comment: Thanks, that did help me to go where I'm at now: it finally works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got it working like this:

- Make a new connector
- Convert connector to group
- Make text fields
- Add the text fields to the group
- Add connection points to the connector (they stay at a fixed distance from the end, it's the way the UML arrows work around the issue)
- Use the shapesheet to bind the textfields to the connection points.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try solution by [y4cine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8012426/y4cine) which you can find in VisioGuy forum's thread [Insert shape data values in sub-shape text](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=6318.msg25957;topicseen#msg25957)
[image: gif]

### [Video description](https://youtu.be/Y9nH38RrMhE)

**UPDATE** you cant download file from VisioGuy's forum without registration. I asked the author for permission to publish the code here, he kindly allowed it.

```
Option Explicit
' This code originally published http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=6318.msg25957;topicseen#msg25957

Private Sub cmRun_Click()
    Dim shp As Shape, shp2 As Shape
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Select Case ActiveWindow.Selection.Count
    Case 0:
        MsgBox "You need to select a shape to perform the operation"
        Exit Sub
    Case 1:
        Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection(1)
        ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
        ActiveWindow.Select shp, visSelect
        ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy
        On Error Resume Next
        shp.ConvertToGroup
        On Error GoTo 0
        If shp.OneD = False Then
        shp.OpenDrawWindow.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Shape.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SelectAll
        Set shp2 = ActiveWindow.Selection(ActiveWindow.Selection.Count)
            shp2.Cells("PinX").Formula = shp.NameU & "!width*0.5"
            shp2.Cells("PinY").Formula = shp.NameU & "!height*0.5"

        shp2.DeleteSection visSectionProp
        shp2.SendToBack
        ActiveWindow.Close
        shp.DeleteSection visSectionFirstComponent
        End If
        If shp.SectionExists(visSectionProp, False) Then
            listProps.Clear
            For i = 0 To shp.Section(visSectionProp).Count - 1
                listProps.AddItem shp.Section(visSectionProp).Row(i).Name
            Next i
        Else
            MsgBox "Your shape does not have shape data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Case Else:
        MsgBox "please select only one shape"
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    
End Sub
Private Sub cmInsert_Click()
    Dim shp As Shape, shp2 As Shape
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Select Case ActiveWindow.Selection.Count
    Case 0:
        MsgBox "You need to select a shape to perform the operation"
        Exit Sub
    Case 1:
        Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection(1)
        If shp.SectionExists(visSectionProp, False) Then
            For i = 0 To listProps.ListCount - 1
                If listProps.Selected(i) Then
                    insertField shp, listProps.List(i)
                End If
            Next i
        Else
            MsgBox "Your shape does not have shape data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Case Else:
        MsgBox "please select only one shape"
        Exit Sub
    End Select

End Sub

Sub insertField(shp As Shape, field As String)
Dim shp2 As Shape
Dim shpChars As Visio.Characters

    If Not shp.SectionExists(visSectionControls, False) Then
        shp.AddSection visSectionControls
    End If
    shp.AddRow visSectionControls, visRowLast, visTagDefault

    Set shp2 = shp.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
    shp2.TextStyle = "Normal"
    shp2.LineStyle = "Text Only"
    shp2.FillStyle = "Text Only"
    Set shpChars = shp2.Characters
    shpChars.Begin = 0
    shpChars.End = 0
    shpChars.AddCustomFieldU "sheet." & shp.ID & "!prop." & field, visFmtNumGenNoUnits
    shp2.Cells("PinX").Formula = "sheet." & shp.ID & "!controls.row_" & shp.RowCount(visSectionControls)
    shp2.Cells("PinY").Formula = "sheet." & shp.ID & "!controls.row_" & shp.RowCount(visSectionControls) & ".Y"
    shp2.Cells("Width").FormulaU = "textwidth(thetext)"
    shp2.Cells("Height").FormulaU = "textheight(thetext, textwidth(thetext))"

End Sub
```

[Download DisplayProps.vss](https://github.com/Surrogate-TM/surrogate-tm.github.io/blob/master/forum/y4cine/DisplayProps.vss)

Comment: Thank you! I indeed registered at the website and tried downloading it. Then visio decided it didn't trust the source and disabled it anyways :(

Comment: You can watch these files [there](https://github.com/Surrogate-TM/surrogate-tm.github.io/tree/master/forum/y4cine)